# What is the difference between "CONNECT" and "GET HTTPS"?

Tags: networking, proxy, https, http-proxy

Before getting to the real question, let me explain how my project works: for sake of simplicity, my proxy is on my laptop, where the client (my browser) also is; the remote server will be, for example, YouTube.

The client is connected to a specific port of the proxy thanks to SwitchOmega plugin: the client wants to connect to www.youtube.com and the proxy gets the following request:

```
CONNECT www.youtube.com:443 HTTP/1.1
Host: www.youtube.com:443
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36
```

I was told that when a proxy gets a `CONNECT` request, it should open a TCP connection to IP:Port, return a `200 OK` message to client and send data until one side of the connection is closed.

With another plugin that tracks HTTP requests, HTTP Trace, I see a different request on my browser:

```
GET https://www.youtube.com/
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
and other data...
```

So, why my proxy receives `CONNECT www.youtube.com:443 HTTP/1.1` while HTTP Trace shows `GET https://www.youtube.com/`? Do they mean the same thing?

Comment: So...`CONNECT` is used to establish a tunnel connection, and `GET https` is sent by the client asking for resources to the remote server after the successfull connection created by `CONNECT` request?

Comment: `CONNECT` is used to establish a TCP/IP tunnel, but not necessarily an SSL connection, and `GET` simply retrieves resources.

Comment: So `GET https` means a previous `CONNECT` to port 443?

Comment: I parse `CONNECT www.youtube.com:443 HTTP/1.1` and get the port number after `:`, that's why I said 443.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**CONNECT** deals with the request

> **CONNECT**
>
> The CONNECT method converts the request connection to a transparent TCP/IP 
>   tunnel, usually to facilitate SSL-encrypted communication (HTTPS) through an unencrypted HTTP proxy.

While **GET** retrieves the data.

> **GET**
>
> The GET method requests a representation of the specified resource. Requests using GET should only retrieve data and should have
>   no other effect. (This is also true of some other HTTP methods.)  The
>   W3C has published guidance principles on this distinction, saying,
>   "Web application design should be informed by the above principles,
>   but also by the relevant limitations."

[Source - Hypertext Transfer Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are dealing with a cosmetic issue.

`GET https://www.youtube.com/` is most likely just what is logged to indicate that the fetching is done with `GET`, and the target is `https://www.youtube.com`.

There is no standardised way for a proxy to support `GET https://` URIs, it was mooted a couple years back at the IETF HTTP WG but discarded for various reasons (trust issues with proxies mainly if I recall)

It is very unlikely to be the request sent to the proxy. As others have said, `CONNECT` is used to connect to `www.youtube.com:443`, then there would be some other GET request which does not contain the scheme (protocol) or authority (server:port etc) parts of the URI.

In your example it would be:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
host: www.youtube.com:443
```