# Manually setting a proxy in a command works, but not setting it in proxychains

Tags: networking, proxy

192.168.2.4 is a machine running a Squid Proxy on port 3128, and a web server on port 80 only accessible via this proxy.

If I run:

```
$ curl 192.168.2.4 --proxy 192.168.2.4:3128
```

It works perfectly and cURL outputs the contents of the homepage. Now, when I try to use ProxyChains:

```
$ cat proxychains.conf
strict_chain
tcp_read_time_out 15000
tcp_connect_time_out 8000
[ProxyList]
http 192.168.2.4 3128

$ proxychains curl 192.168.2.4
ProxyChains-3.1 (http://proxychains.sf.net)
|S-chain|-<>-192.168.2.4:3128-<><>-192.168.2.4:80-<--denied
curl: (7) Couldn't connect to server
```

It doesn't work. It seems to connect correctly to the Squid Proxy, but not to the end web server.

Any idea why this would be the case?

Answer (score 3):

I have discovered with `wireshark` that when talking to a proxy `curl` uses `GET` while `proxychains` uses `CONNECT`. The difference is explained here: [What is the difference between “CONNECT” and “GET HTTPS”?](https://superuser.com/a/1056540/432690)

[Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11698002) mentions proxy chaining with `CONNECT`. I think `GET` cannot be chained, that's why `proxychains` uses `CONNECT`.

Now, [Wikipedia article about HTTP tunneling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_tunnel#HTTP_CONNECT_tunneling) says the folowing about `CONNECT`:

> Not all HTTP Proxy Servers support this feature, and even those that do, may limit the behaviour (for example only allowing connections to the default HTTPS port 443, or blocking traffic which doesn't appear to be SSL).

Indeed, the [Squid Cache Wiki](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/HTTPS#CONNECT_tunnel) states (emphasis mine):

> It is important to notice that the protocols passed through `CONNECT` are not limited to the ones Squid normally handles. **Quite literally anything that uses a two-way TCP connection can be passed through a `CONNECT` tunnel.** This is why the Squid default ACLs start with `deny CONNECT !SSL_Ports` and why you must have a very good reason to place any type of allow rule above them.

I guess your `squid.conf` includes a line like this:

```
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_Ports
```

I have found [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31831631) that says **it's enough to comment this line out**. Checked, it works. However, if you don't want to punch such a big hole in your proxy then try to add the following three lines to your `squid.conf`:

```
acl myserver dst 192.168.2.4
acl myport port 80
http_access allow CONNECT myserver myport
# the original uncommented line must be below, like this
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_Ports
```