# Difference between SSH Tunnel and HTTP Tunnel

Tags: remote-desktop, proxy, port-forwarding, ssh-tunnel

I am trying to understand the difference between SSH port-forwarding/tunneling and HTTP tunneling. So when I try RDP over SSH tunnel it works, but when try the same over an established secure HTTP tunnel it doesn't. I am trying to understand the core difference or reason for this difference in tunneling.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible reason HTTP tunneling doesn't work for arbitrary protocols: [`deny CONNECT !SSL_Ports` or similar rule](https://superuser.com/a/1200601/432690).

Comment: What software are you using to establish the HTTP tunnel, and how are you using it together with the RDP client?

Comment: In my case the local port on the client side was the issue, it was changing dynamically, I bound it to a static port on the client side and it worked. Thanks!